# React routing : URL gets changed but content from component didn't load

Tags: reactjs, react-routing

I am trying to implement react routing in basic react application.

I have implemented it but somehow its not working properly.

URL gets changed but content from component didnt load.

Here is path for code : https://github.com/AshuDeshpande/ReactSampleApplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

src/app/index.js

```
<Route exact path="/" Component={Root} />
```

should be

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Root} />
```

Comment: thanks.. its working now..